# show specific values on the list from map

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make bluetooth app using flutter and reactive blue library.

I would like to show specific value of name on the device scan list.

Now this code show all the device which was scanned.
but I wanna show the list which contain name of {mydevice}.

Here is code

```
Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                children: widget.scannerState.discoveredDevices
                    .map(
                      (device) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(device.name),
                        subtitle: Text("${device.id}\nRSSI: ${device.rssi}"),
                        leading: const BluetoothIcon(),
                        onTap: () async {
                          widget.stopScan();
                          await Navigator.push<void>(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) =>
                                      DeviceDetailScreen(device: device)));
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
```

you can see all the code here

https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/master/example/lib/src/ui/device_list.dart

Answer (score 2):

Try this please

```
 Flexible(
                          child: ListView(
                            children: widget.scannerState.discoveredDevices
                                .map(
                                  (device) {
                                    if(condition)
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text(device.name),
                                      subtitle: Text(
                                          "${device.id}\nRSSI: ${device.rssi}"),
                                      leading: const BluetoothIcon(),
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        widget.stopScan();
                                        await Navigator.push<void>(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (_) =>
                                                    DeviceDetailScreen(
                                                        device: device)));
                                      },
                                    )
                                  }
                            )
                                .toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
```